# How to sum array value of duplicate data on java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I Have JSON data from arraylist

AS IS :

```
[{"CategoryID":"2","Discontinued":"0","ProductID":"3","ProductName":"Aniseed Syrup","QuantityPerUnit":"12 - 550 ml bottles","ReorderLevel":"25","SupplierID":"1","UnitPrice":"10000","UnitsInStock":"13","UnitsOnOrder":"70"},{"CategoryID":"2","Discontinued":"1","ProductID":"5","ProductName":"Chef Anton\u0027s Gumbo Mix","QuantityPerUnit":"36 boxes","ReorderLevel":"0","SupplierID":"2","UnitPrice":"21350","UnitsInStock":"0","UnitsOnOrder":"0"},{"CategoryID":"2","Discontinued":"0","ProductID":"3","ProductName":"Aniseed Syrup","QuantityPerUnit":"12 - 550 ml bottles","ReorderLevel":"25","SupplierID":"1","UnitPrice":"10000","UnitsInStock":"13","UnitsOnOrder":"70"}]
```

How to be JSON data merge by product id & sum unitprice & quantity in java android with arraylist?

TO BE :

```
[{"CategoryID":"2","Discontinued":"0","ProductID":"3","ProductName":"Aniseed Syrup","QuantityPerUnit":"2","ReorderLevel":"25","SupplierID":"1","UnitPrice":"20000","UnitsInStock":"13","UnitsOnOrder":"70"},{"CategoryID":"2","Discontinued":"1","ProductID":"5","ProductName":"Chef Anton\u0027s Gumbo Mix","QuantityPerUnit":"36 boxes","ReorderLevel":"0","SupplierID":"2","UnitPrice":"21350","UnitsInStock":"0","UnitsOnOrder":"0"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What was your approach? How did it go?

Answer (score 0):

You can map the values to objects, by writing your own map function, or using a json parser library. Then you can add all of the objects to a `Set<T>` with the type of your object.